# How to speed up rails development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, development-environment

I'm running Jruby on Rails on Windows 7. Every time I make some changes in my code I have to restart the server (because I'm using the sidekiq gem for background job processing) and this is the procedure for doing that

> In the first CMD window

First I need to kill all java processes(jruby on rails). Otherwise the server will complain that the address is already  in use

```
taskkill /im java.exe /im javaw.exe /f
```

remove the pid file

```
rm -vf tmp/pids/*
```

start the server

```
rails server
```

> In the second CMD window

```
bundle exec sidekiq
```

This is starting to feel sluggish since I have to do this every time I change a code.

I looked around and found this

```
find /your/application_directory -name=*.rb -exec ruby -c {} \;
```

What the above command does is loop through all files in the directory and check for syntax errors, but this doesn't seem to work in windows cmd even though I have the GNU find tool.

**Is there any way to make changes in code and view it in the application without all this rigmarole? Do all other developers follow the same routine?**

Comment: why dont you put all this stuff in a shell script?

Comment: They're already inside a batch script.

Comment: Consider using linux machine for your develpment, or mac since it's unix based, you'll have much better experience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of googling I've found this:
https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/209#issuecomment-8352050

> If you really want code reloading in development, you can just run sidekiq inline by adding this to development.rb
>
> `require 'sidekiq/testing/inline'`
>
> With that, you don't even need to run the sidekiq process.

Which seems helpful (I also recommend reading the whole thread)